# Salir de un programa cuando un resultado se repita 3 veces

Tags: c

El problema dicta lo siguiente:

> Mientras el usuario lo desee: estar tirando un dado hasta que salgan 3 seis SEGUIDOS. Si no salen tres seis seguidos no se saldrá de este ciclo.
>
> Cada vez que resulten los 3 seis seguidos, se mostrara un mensaje de felicitación por haberlo logrado.
>
> Al final mostrará el total de veces en que se lograron los 3 seis seguidos.

No puedo usar arrays, solo ciclos (puedo anidarlos).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main {
int num_dado , cont_seis = 0, suma = 0 , decision, cont_victoria = 0 ;
 srand (time(NULL)); 
 
 do 
 {
   num_dado = rand() % 6 + 1 ; 
      printf("\tNumero aleatorio generado: %d\n",num_dado);

    do
    {
      num_dado = rand() % 6 + 1 ; 
      printf("\tNumero aleatorio generado: %d\n",num_dado);

    if (num_dado == 6)
    suma += num_dado ;

    }
    while( num_dado <= 6 && suma != 18); 
 }
    while(num_dado != 6 && suma != 18);
    //printf("Las veces que se lograron 3 seis seguidos fueron: %d \n",cont_victoria);
   printf("%d",suma);
}
```

Mi idea era que al identificar 3 seis pues la suma seria 18 y ahí iba parar el ciclo, pero me olvide del punto que debía de ser seguidos, y no encuentro la manera de hacerlo

También pensé en revisarlo con una variable anterior pero no llegue a resolverlo. No es necesario que lo resuelvan, solo que me ayuden diciéndome cómo puedo identificar si 3 números sin iguales y estan seguidos dentro de un ciclo

El código que solo muestra lo que mencione.

Gracias.

Comment: En caso no salga 6 solo resetea la variable, es decir haces `suma = 0;`

Comment: Gracias, fue de ayuda, solo era necesario eso en mi codigo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que te están pidiendo es que uses un bucle para tirar los dados. La idea es que no hagas 3 tiradas explícitas de dados.

Por otro lado te dicen que no puedes usar arrays simplemente para que no empecéis a tirar por caminos que os van a alejar de la solución.

Tirar dados hasta que obtener tres veces seguidas un 6

```
int contador = 0;
while (contador < 3)
{
    int dado = rand() % 6 + 1;
    printf("Ha salido un %d", dado);
    if (dado == 6)
        contador ++;
    else
        contador = 0;
}
```

Y ahora tienes que hacer que el código anterior se repita mientras el usuario quiera seguir jugando.

Cada vez que le preguntes al usuario será porque has conseguido la secuencia pedida... puedes usar un contador para llevar esa cuenta...

Comment: ¿Qué sería **pomara**?

Comment: Graciasss, tienes razón, lograste que mi código se hiciera tan pequeño, pero logre razonarlo mejor, la lógica es importante.

Comment: @Mateo No habrá querido escribir "para"? Ya lo dirá cuando vea los comentarios

Comment: @Cuauhtli no lo sé. Simplemente era para que lo note y lo corrija.

Comment: Si, supongo que quiso escribir "para".

Comment: @Mateo escribí la respuesta desde el movil, y aunque fui despacio, se me coló esa errata. Bien visto